# Importing external jars on Sublime Text 3 using Javatar

Tags: java, jar, import, sublimetext3

I decided to switch to Sublime Text 3 from DrJava because I really like the visuals of Sublime Text 3. I installed the Javatar package and used the dependency option to add an external jar, but the compiler (Command + B; I use a mac) does not seem to identify with the jar files. Does anyone know if this is currently a bug in javatar or is there something I might be doing wrong? I made sure that the jars would also be in the parent folder to make sure that that wasn't causing the problem. If there's another way of importing jars, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javatar, you can only build your classes with all the settings (you have set so far) by using Builds command in Javatar menu.

Pressing "Command+Shift+K" then "Command+Shift+B" will display a build dialog, showing you all available options you can build.

The "Command+B" itself is comes with Sublime Text 3, hence that is build with Sublime Text's build system not with Javatar's.

The dependencies are not required to be inside parent folder. You can leave it anywhere you want and Javatar should compile your classes with them properly.

Hope you found this useful,

spywhere